# Django recursive model

Tags: django, recursion, filetree

I'm making my own "cloud server" with django, for my projects and files.
I'm trying to create tree file structure, but I cant figure out the way to do it.
And how I can make username based URL, like (username/root/home/Documents/...)
I'm also interested of some good links and examples of authentication and django style cloud server solutions.
**models.py**

```
class BasicFile(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_edit = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    sub_folders = models.IntegerField()
    sub_files = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_name
```

**views.py**

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'cloud/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'project_file'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return ProjectFile.objects.all()
```

**urls.py**

```
re_path(r'^(?P<username>)/$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
re_path(r'^(?P<username>/f1/f1_child)/$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to create a nested structure from your file objects you could create an optional relationship so that files can have 'parents' which you could then build up a tree from.

To do so you could add a field to your model;

```
parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True)
```

This may help with your understanding of authentication & users; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication

Comment: @ markwalker_  When i add `parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
`,It gives me error about `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to' ` My plan was to make tree data structure with one model, is that even possible?

Comment: Yeah, this would give you a hierarchy using only 1 model. What version of Django are you using because looking at the docs, that's as it states so should be fine; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey - post the full stacktrace of the error if you can't figure it out.